# Count same values in column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I am trying to count Same values in a column and want it to return a count there off.

```
| ITEM  | COUNT |
+-------+-------+
| GREEN |  1    |
| GREEN |  2    |
| GREEN |  3    |
| RED   |  1    |
| RED   |  2    |
```

I tried

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEM) AS Row
```

But that only counts each line 1 - 1000

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to include a `partition by` clause with the row_number function. This makes the row_number restart from 1 for each new type of item.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY ITEM) AS Row
```

this would give you a result like:

```
item    Row
GREEN   1
GREEN   2
GREEN   3
RED     1
RED     2
```

Comment: Perfect Worked 100% Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY ITEM) AS Row
```

or

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY COUNT) AS Row
```

You can have count of each `ITEM` like this:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM) As CountByItem
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will count same values in table

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
Group by item
```